# Python test fixture to run a single test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, nose

I'm looking for something like ruby rspec's `focus` metadata or elixir's mix tags to run a single python test.

#### Ruby RSpec Example:

```
# $ rspec spec
it 'runs a single test', :focus do 
  expect(2).to eq(2)
end
```

#### Elixir ExUnit & Mix Example:

```
# $ mix test --only focus
@tag :focus
test "only run this test" do
  assert true
end
```

Is this possible / available with any python test runner and fixture combo? Running single tests by specifying nested `module.class.test_name` via command line args can become very verbose in larger projects.

So Something like:

#### Desired Python Code:

```
# $ nosetests --only focus

from tests.fixtures import focus

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    @focus
    def test_all_the_things(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say hello to [pytest mark](http://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/pytestmark.html). You can create a focus tag, assign to any test case or method and then run tests with `pytest -v -m focus` command. For example:

```
import unittest
import pytest

class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_method1(self):
        # I won't be executed with focus mark
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    @pytest.mark.focus
    def test_method2(self):  
        # I will be executed with focus mark          
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

will run `test_method2`. To run all methods within some TestCase, you simply mark a class:

```
import unittest
import pytest

@pytest.mark.focus
class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

You will need to register your custom marks in `pytest.ini` like

```
[pytest]
markers =
    focus: what is being developed right now
```

To see the available marks, run `pytest --markers`.

Comment: Am I missing something? AFAIK this way will run no tests if no mark is set, so it is not possible to work the same way as rspec allows, where you start to run the full testsuite, then use focus to drill down to groups or individual tests.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and wanted to imitate the same behaviour that `rspec` provides for ruby, where the entire test suite is ran when there are no focused tests, but when there are it only runs the focused tests.

The setup is fairly similar to what Piotr suggested, but adds one extra step to filter out the selected tests.

1. Configure the marker as suggested by Piotr in your `pytest.ini` or `pyproject.toml`:

   ```
   [pytest]
   markers = 
       focus: what is being developed right now
   ```
2. Add the following code to your root `conftest.py`

   ```py
   def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session: pytest.Session, config: Any, items: list[pytest.Item]):
       focused = [i for i in items if i.get_closest_marker("focus")]

       if focused:
           items[:] = focused
   ```

This will filter the collected tests when there are one or more tests that have a focus marker. Combining this with `pytest-testmon` gives you the same behaviour as `guard` provides when coming from a ruby background.

Comment: Your setup in `conftest.py` must be missing something, I get `ERROR  - NameError: name 'Any' is not defined`

Comment: `from typing import Any` is used here. But feel free to change the code to remove the type hints so you don't even need to import them.